# Magento only responding from public network. Local network gives 404

Tags: php, apache, magento, curl, dns

When I run a `curl` `www.example.com` from outside my web server, everything goes fine. But when I do it from internal server shell, I receive a `404` (the domain is not resolving locally).

This problem is affecting the API too.

How can I solve this? This server is an `Ubuntu 12.04`, `Apache 2.2`, `PHP 5.3.10`, `Vitualmin` with latest version.

**Edit:** My test and its full output:

`curl http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1`

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

<html><head>

<title>404 Not Found</title>

</head><body>

<h1>Not Found</h1>

<p>The requested URL /index.php/api/v2_soap was not found on this server.</p>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem wasn't on Magento.**

I have added an entry to `/etc/hosts` in my **local** computer poiting for this domain and, since I had forgotten that, I had the illusion the domain in question had its DNS correctly propagated.

**So, the real problem was that: the DNS wasn't really propagated**

With the [last comment of s1lv3r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451527/magento-only-responding-from-public-network-local-network-gives-404#comment37839904_24452219) I realized the nonsense I had done.

In the end, I had removed this entry in my hosts file (initially made to test the new server) and concluded the DNS configuration for the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also not ping that domain from within a shell?

If this is a DNS problem and the domain doesn't resolve correctly to localhost the simplest way to solve this problem would be to add a line like

```
127.0.0.1       www.example.com
```

to your local hosts file in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: One of the strange behaviours is that I can ping it normally :P

Comment: @Paulocoghi Can you post the full output of the curl request?

Comment: Done (in the question) ;)

Comment: @Paulocoghi Sorry, but can you do it again using verbose output? Like `curl -v http://exmaple.com/` ;-)

Comment: @Paulocoghi hmmm ... you said everything is fine from outside. As you now posted your live-domain I had a try and I'm also getting a 404. So either the file is really not there or your vhost isn't configured correctly (not pointing to the right root-dir). :-)